# Is it bad to have no default target in a Makefile

Tags: linux, makefile

Is it bad practice to have something like:

```
all:
```

in a Makefile, to enforce the user to specify the target, and ignore the default one?

Comment: Depends on if you want/need to force the user to specify a target. The convention is that the default target is `all` (i.e. it's the first one specified) and builds the code without deploying it. This is not a question with a real answer, though.

Comment: Make is just a tool, if you have a good reason for disabling the default goal and don't think it will annoy your users, do what you like.

Comment: I'm surprised to see this question closed as not constructive.  I came here seeking a best practice around disabling the implicit default target in my Makefile because I find it a confusing default.  This question asks that explicitly and is very constructive to me perhaps with a small tweak to the title.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

`all` is not necessarily the default target. The default target is the first one defined in your makefile. Also, if you leave an empty target as the default one (and are sure that there's no other `all` target with rules somewhere else in the makefile), `make`'s behavior might be a little bit puzzling. I'd suggest to let the default behavior print an appropriate error message, such as:

```
error:
        @echo "Please choose one of the following target: compile, install, uninstall"
        @# Alternatively: "Please RTFI(nstall)F(ile)"
        @exit 2
```